# В чём разница между new mysqli и mysqli_connect?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysqli

В чём разница между `new mysqli()` и `mysqli_connect()`?

Comment: Что пишут по этому поводу в мануалах?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new mysqli()` - это объекто-ориентированный стиль, `mysqli_connect()` - процедурный.

В конечном итоге делают они одно и тоже - создают "соединение" с бд. 
Если вы пишите приложение на функциях и преимущественно без ООП - то используйте процедурный стиль, если с ООП -  то объектный, чтобы не нарушать стиль.